# NPM error while installing angular-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, angular-cli

I'm trying to reinstall `angular-cli` tool to get the newest version. I did upgrade the `graceful-fs`, `tough-cookies` and `lodash` before installation. Now when I try to install `angular-cli` globally it produces this error:

```
(node: 7736) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I'm running `cmd.exe` as an administrator, so I really can't find the solution what can be wrong with this one. Other global or local installations are successful.

Comment: Beyond running as an admin, another reason npm may not be able to write to those files is that they are in use somewhere.  Maybe check for that?

Comment: Nothing opened. I tried to install it without running anything and without any unuseful services or processes. I tried the newest Kali Linux (debian) too, but nothing. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I tried in many ways but nothing was working for me when I installed Windows 7 on a virtual machine and installed the latest *Nodejs* on it. Then using *npm* I installed angular/cli and everything is working well on that windows 7 :)

Even in windows 7 in actual pc it's working well so I guess it has some problems with Windows, mac or Linux version and Windows 7 is most effective for it...

Comment: I had it installed on Win 7 64x but it wasn't working so I installed it on Win 10 64x and now it works but still shows the "EventEmitter Error"... wierd.

Comment: what was your node version and npm version?

Comment: latest ... I'n not sure now... node was 6.6.0 and npm probably 3.10.7